# How to pass a value between recursive calls of a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a function called inorderHelperArray that takes an array and a pointer to the root node of a Binary Search Tree and, using in-order traversal, takes the data from each Node in the BST and puts the data into an array. Here is what that function looks like:

```
void BinTree::inorderHelperArray(NodeData* a[], Node *startNode) const{
    /*static*/ int i = 0;
    //This code works if I set i as a static int.
    //However, I cannot call this function again, as i is never reset to 0.
    
    if(startNode != nullptr){
        inorderHelperArray(a, startNode->left);
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        a[i++] = startNode->data;
        inorderHelperArray(a, startNode->right);
    }
}
```

I can only get the inorderHelperArray function to work properly if i is declared as a static in `static int i = 0;`. However, this is a problem, as if I ever call inorderHelperArray again, the code breaks. i is never reset to 0, and I end up assigning values in the array to wherever i "left off". For instance, if I call inorderHelperArray and the BST has 13 nodes, then i would be 13. If I then called inorderHelperArray **again**, i would start off at 13, meaning that I would be assgining values in the array I am trying to create starting at index 13. If i is not declared as static `int i=0;`, then that doesnt work, as each time there is a recursive call to the function, i remains at 0.

Can anyone give me some suggestions of how I can get the above code to work properly? Is there a way I can get the benefit of a static variable but have it reset itself once I exit inorderHelperArray after the final recursive call?

Comment: How about passing `i` as an argument as well? You could make it a reference if you need.

Comment: That makes sense and I thought of adding such a parameter to my function as well. But I wasnt sure how to determine how many recursive function calls were occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret a call `inorderHelperArray(NULL, NULL)` as a valid call, a reset request, and reset `i` to `0` on such occasion. so before calling it with the actual data you'd make this "reset request" call, always.

So the function would look something like

```
void BinTree::inorderHelperArray(NodeData* a[], Node *startNode) const{
    static int i = 0;

    if(startNode != nullptr){
        inorderHelperArray(a, startNode->left);
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        a[i++] = startNode->data;
        inorderHelperArray(a, startNode->right);
    }
    else{   
        if( a == nullptr) i = 0;   ///// NB
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @WillNess,

That makes sense. Just to make sure I understand, after every "valid" called to ```inorderHelperArray``` (valid being where I wanted to actually convert a BST to an array), I would need to also have a "reset" call to the function. Here is an example of what I mean:

```inorderHelperArray(a, root1);
inorderHelperArray(nullptr,nullptr);
inorderHelperArray(b,root2);
```

Comment: yes. I would say to also run it _before_ any valid call, just to be sure. you might even package that up as one function, and always call _it_ when you need this functionality, treating these other "two" function uses as some internal detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you change your interface.  Probably the best change would be to pass in a vector by reference, and just push_back onto it as you visit your data.  Due to move semantics, this should be efficient to return.

```
void inorderHelper(std::vector<NodeData*>& a, Node *startNode) {
    if(startNode != nullptr) {
        inorderHelper(a, startNode->left);
        a.push_back(startNode->data);
        inorderHelper(a, startNode->right);
    }
}

auto inorder(Node * startNode) {
    std::vector<NodeData*> result;
    inorderHelper(result, startNode);
    return result;
}
```

Another approach, closer to your original--but only if you must use an array (which is IMHO a bad idea, because there is no protection against memory overwrites, and is error prone and likely to cause leaks), is to pass the integer through by reference, in a similar way that I did the vector above:

```
void inorderHelper(NodeData* a[], int& i, NodeData *startNode) {
    if(startNode != nullptr) {
        inorderHelper(a, i, startNode->left);
        a[i++] = startNode->data;
        inorderHelper(a, startNode->right);
    }
}

void inorder(NodeData* a[], Node * startNode) {
    int i = 0;
    inorderHelper(a, i, startNode);
}
```

I removed these functions from a class so they can be shown in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You might do the following:

```
int BinTree::inorderHelperArray(NodeData* a[], Node *startNode, int i = 0) const
{
    if (startNode != nullptr) {
        i = inorderHelperArray(a, startNode->left, i);
        std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
        a[i++] = startNode->data;
        i = inorderHelperArray(a, startNode->right, i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

but using `std::vector` as result seems better:

```
// private
void BinTree::inorderHelperArrayRec(Node *startNode, std::vector<NodeData*>& res) const
{
    if (startNode != nullptr) {
        inorderHelperArray(startNode->left);
        std::cout << "i: " << res.size() << std::endl;
        res.push_back(startNode->data);
        inorderHelperArray(startNode->right);
    }
}
// public interface
std::vector<NodeData*> BinTree::inorderHelperArray(Node *startNode) const
{
    std::vector<NodeData*> res;
    inorderHelperArrayRec(startNode, res);
    return res;
}
```